# How can kafka connect to consume messages from pubsub emulator running inside container

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, emulation, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Google based doc, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator, mentions how application can connect to the Pub/Sub emulator. But in case of Kafka, how to connect to consume messages? Is there a connector kafka can use to reach pubsub emulator?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.. There's code there for consuming messages from the emulator, so **yes**, you can **forward** what you consume there into a Kafka topic. Kafka isn't going to connect on its own

Comment: The Google Cloud document that you have shared is only for applications which are built using Google Cloud Client Libraries. Please consider following this [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kafka-pubsub-emulator/tree/alpha) for using the Pub/Sub emulator for Kafka.